# Como mostrar mi ruta en linux, pero usando lenguaje c

Tags: c, linux, xubuntu

Necesito obtener la ruta actual de mi carpeta en linux, usando lenguaje c, alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Comment: ¿ Que quiere decir `la ruta actual de mi carpeta` ? ¿ Tu `$HOME` ? ¿ Tu directorio de trabajo actual ?

Comment: Necesito crear un archivo "archivo.c" que al yo compilar y luego ejecutar me bote una cadena, esta cadena debe contener la ruta de la carpeta donde está el mismo archivo.c

Comment: como si ejecutar pwd

Comment: Y si parados en la carpeta `\tmp` invocamos `\home\usuario\archivo`, que debería retornar `\tmp` o `\home\usuario`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber donde estas parado en el momento de ejecucion proba con `getcwd` este te lo devuelve, para usarlo tenes que incluir la lib `#include <unistd.h>`. Espero que te sirva, un saludo.